# How to organize desktop and mobile views separately (Zend Framework)

Tags: php, zend-framework, mobile

I'm already running a desktop website with views and template files. Now I would like to develop a mobile version of my website.

I've already detect smart devices by using WURFL library within my own Plugin and I inject that plugin during application initialization.

I'm using Zend ContextSwitch Helper to change the context of current view file with suffix 'mobile' like: index.mobile.phtml.

What I need to organize my existing views under separate folder for mobile like: `/views/mobile/index.phtml` not as `/views/index.mobile.phtml` (same folder).

```
//Add Context
$this->addContext('html', array('suffix' => 'mobile'));
```

Please advise me how can I tell application to search mobile views under mobile for every views.

**I'm using Zend Framework 1.12 version**

Answer (score 0):

Your desired approach may be confusing because `/views/mobile/index.phtml` will refer to "mobile" controller

You may override this by simply changing the template path destination for mobile templates. `$view->setScriptPath('mobile')`

Another way is to store them in the same folder but with different suffix `/views/controller-name/action-name.mobile.phtml` 
You can achieve this just by changing the view extension using view renderer.  `$viewRenderer->setViewSuffix('mobile.phtml');`

Or you may rewrite your templates using responsive webdesign :-)